# Launching Zathura from Vim

Tags: shell, vim, neovim

I have the following little shell script, called `md`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Error: No argument supplied"
else
    (pandoc -t pdf $1 | zathura - &)
fi
```

It works fine in my terminal, allowing me to run, say, `md foo.md` and launch Zathura with the generated pdf. However, I've tried adding a custom Vim command to do the same, and it doesn't work! Here's the command from my `init.vim`:

```
command Md ! md %:p
```

When I run `:Md` in Vim in a Markdown file I get the following output from Vim:

```
:! md /absolute/path/to/file.md
```

and Zathura launches, but with an "empty" file, i.e. it says "[No name]" down at the bottom. If I copy-paste the command that Vim says it ran, and run it in my terminal, Zathura launches just the same, but with the file displayed.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The problem wasn't with the difference between reading from a file or from a buffer, (although I did implement @amphetamachine's answer because reading from buffer is more nice), but instead it was the interaction between pandoc and zathura when running as background processes.

I think the fault here lies with Zathura, which when spawned as a background process doesn't properly receive pipe input. You're supposed to use `--fork` instead.

The final version looks like this:

init.vim

```
command! -buffer -range=% Md w !md
map <F5> :silent Md<CR>
```

The md script

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z $1 ]; then                                                                                            
    pandoc -t pdf | zathura --fork -
 else
    pandoc -t pdf $1 | zathura --fork -
fi
```

This properly gives command back to Vim and works both there, and in my terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You may have better luck piping the contents of the current buffer to the script instead of relying on files.

In `~/.vimrc`:

```
command! -buffer -range=% Md <line1>,<line2>w !md
```

Your `md` script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
pandoc -t pdf | zathura - &
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same result as before.

Comment: Well, I've got some progress. By removing the & it means that now it works. However, this locks up my Vim in the meantime. In fact, even something like `cat - &` doesn't work but `cat -` does.